# Show/hide all page tooltips on button click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I am trying to show all tooltips present on the page on button click. The second button click should hide all tooltips. It is also important that this should work in IE 11

```
<button type="button"  onclick="showAlltooltips();" style="float:right;font-size:medium"></button>

<button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="title2"></button>

<label class="form-check-label text-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="title2" style="margin-right:10px"></label>


<script>
function showAlltooltips()
{
       $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('show');
}
</script>
```

Comment: *I am trying to show all tooltips present on the page on button click* Please elaborate your your question - this much is not enough to provide a working answer.

Comment: What information do you need ?  I have multiple buttons and other elements on the page that have tooltips I need to show them all on click .

Comment: You want to show all tooltips on a page using ONE button click ?

Comment: Yes . and hide them all on second button click. It should also work in IE browser

Comment: what version is your IE. I am not sure if it even work properly these days. It going to be deprecated / end soon! -  Please edit your question to add this info.

Comment: IE 11 . I have edited the question .  I hope it will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function showAlltooltips()
{
if ($('body').hasClass('is-show-tooltip')) {
       $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');
       $('body').removeClass('is-show-tooltip');
} else {
       $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('show');
       $('body').addClass('is-show-tooltip');
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Tried it doesn't work for some reason. Can IE browser be a problem ?